# If my mac was stolen and it goes "offline" in iCloud, is there a chance my MBP will go online and show its location again?

Tags: macbook-pro, icloud

I had my mac recently stolen about 48 hours ago and I've been trying to track it's location ever since. Until recently it only showed its last location which was on my college campus, which didn't narrow down its whereabouts. Now it says "offline" on iCloud, is it lost forever?

Comment: There's a chance, but I doubt it. Unless the thief is an idiot, it's unlikely you'll ever see the computer again (either on iCloud or in person).

Comment: Remember that it needs wifi to talk to iCloud, so unless the thief turns it on within range of wifi that has password previously stored..